# How can i sum specific month value with date in pandas frame?

Tags: python, pandas, date, sum

I have a dataset like this

> ID,DATE,NO,MONTH
>
> 1,24/04/2019,6,2019/09
>
> 1,24/04/2019,7,2019/09

And i have months to ad for DATE column.
For example i want to see 24/04/2019 add with 6 month -> 2019/10 in my new column

Error is:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("denemedf.txt", delimiter=",")
print(dataset['DATE'])
dataset['ADDED'] = 0 #new column
data_to_Array = np.asarray(dataset['DATE'])
#print(data_to_Array)

numbers = [3,6]

for i in range(len(data_to_Array)):
    added_value = data_to_Array[i] + numbers[i]
    dataset['ADDED'][i] = added_value

from datetime import datetime
print ( dataset['ADDED'].strftime("%Y/%m") )
```

How can i see this result in dataset['ADDED'] represent like this year/month?

I hope that i explained clear what i want to do.

Expected result is like that:

> ID,DATE,NO,MONTH, ADDED
>
> 1,24/04/2019,6,2019/09,2019/7
>
> 1,24/04/2019,7,2019/09,2019/10

Comment: you can add dates and time using "timedelta" func

Comment: @anky_91 okey i edited

Comment: shouldnt the added column be `2019/10` for the first row? as you are adding `4+6=10`? can you explain how you get 7

Comment: @anky_91 i want add wit numbers in numbers array (numbers = [3,6])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first convert your DATE column string to datetime with this [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).
Then you can use a lambda function to create the new column with [pandas DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html).

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['24/04/2019', '24/04/2019'], 'NO': [6,7]})
dataset['DATE'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['DATE'], '%d/%m/%Y'), axis=1)
dataset['ADDED'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: x['DATE'] + pd.DateOffset(months=x['NO']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), so possible add number of days from list or column, last convert output to strings by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html):

```
numbers = [3,6]
s = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.to_period('m')
df['ADDED'] = (s + np.array(numbers)).dt.strftime("%Y/%m")
print (df)

   ID        DATE  NO    MONTH    ADDED
0   1  24/04/2019   6  2019/09  2019/07
1   1  24/04/2019   7  2019/09  2019/10
```

If need to add `NO` column:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.to_period('m')
df['ADDED'] = (s + df['NO']).dt.strftime("%Y/%m")
print (df)
   ID        DATE  NO    MONTH    ADDED
0   1  24/04/2019   6  2019/09  2019/10
1   1  24/04/2019   7  2019/09  2019/11
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need

```
import pandas as pd

numbers = [3,6]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=["DATE"])
df["ADDED"] = [(d +  pd.DateOffset(months=mon)) for d, mon in zip(df["DATE"], numbers)]  
df["ADDED"] = df["ADDED"].dt.strftime("%Y/%m")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID       DATE  NO     MONTH    ADDED
0   1 2019-04-24   6  2019/09   2019/07
1   1 2019-04-24   7   2019/09  2019/10
```